# How to migrate laravel app from inside docker container to a mysql database outside the container?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

How can I do php artisan migrate from a docker container where the mysql-server is deployed in another container

Here is the Dockerfile of the laravel app

```
FROM php:7.2.19-fpm
FROM composer
FROM octava/php7.4-mysql5.7
RUN mkdir /usr/src/REST-API/
WORKDIR /usr/src/REST-API
COPY . /usr/src/REST-API
RUN cd /usr/src/REST-API
RUN cat .env
RUN composer install
CMD php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

I used mysql/mysql-server:latest for the database container and I ran this command:

```
sudo docker run --name=mysql3.0 -dp 3309:3306 mysql/mysql-server
```

my env file is

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3309
```

An error arise when I do `docker exec -it <container-name> php artisan migrate` from the
container?
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = devices and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you search for "*laravel access docker mysql*" you will find many answers already.  Your `.env` file should use the name of the DB container, in your case `mysql3.0`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928513/can-not-connect-mysql-with-laravel-docker, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185053/connecting-to-dockerized-mysql-database-on-laravel-app, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921378/laravel-with-docker-issue-connecting-mysql, ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not connect mysql with laravel (docker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928513/can-not-connect-mysql-with-laravel-docker)

Comment: I found a new error (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost')

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new network in docker and add these 2 containers(php and mysql) to that network so that they can see each other.
Basically, you are pointing to `DB_HOST` in your `.env` file and it should be accessible to the container running your Laravel app. it could be something like `serverIp:dbPort` or set as a local ip if they are on the same netowrk.
To create a new network run:

```
docker network create -d bridge myNetwork
```

To connect a container to a network run:

```
docker network connect myNetwork containerName
```

Refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) for creating networks in Docker also [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/) for connecting containers to networking